# .NET Selenium + Headless Chrome - Hide 'Page Loading' Cursor?

Tags: .net, vb.net, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am running headless Chrome with the ChromeDriver command prompt set as hidden, and when there is page loading, my mouse cursor switches to the loading cursor (the one that spins).

How can I disable or hide this? I want the testing to be 100% in the background.

```
 Dim options As New ChromeOptions
 options.AddArgument("--headless")
 options.AddArgument("--disable-gpu")
 Dim service As ChromeDriverService = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService
 service.HideCommandPromptWindow = True
 Dim driver As New ChromeDriver(service, options)
 driver.Navigate.GoToUrl("http://example.com")
 driver.Quit()
```

***Version Info***

ChromeDriver 2.35

Chrome 64.0.3282.140

Selenium.WebDriver .NET NuGet Package 3.9.0

Comment: Can you add the version details of the binaries you are using?

Comment: @DebanjanB Updated my question with the requested info